# Can you control output of a Parameter in Visual Force?

Tags: visualforce

I have a VisualForce page that accesses a variable in the URL to determine whether a particular field in the form should be displayed.

I use `($CurrentPage.parameters.example)` to get that variable, which we'll call 'example'.

The thing is, since I use this variable inside Javascript to determine whether or not a part of the form should be displayed, I want some prevention of scripting attacks through this URL variable. Is there a way to limit its size when it's output to the page to, say, 3 characters.

I do use:

```
!JSINHTMLENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.cts)
```

but I don't know what security that provides.

How can I just ensure that what is output to the page is of a certain character length?

Comment: Side comment: does this need to be used in javascript? You can't just use <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$CurrentPage.Parameters.cts == somevalue}" ?

Comment: Great idea LaceySnr. I'm pretty new to VisualForce, so this solution didn't occur to me. And if it doesn't work, I'll go with ca_peterson's exact solution.

Comment: That does work LaceySnr, and is quite elegant. Does using your code provide sufficient XSS prevention? Or should I wrap a JSINHTMLENCODE around the value of the 'rendered' attribute?

Comment: Visualforce markup is all processed on the server and as long as the HTML that's output doesn't contains vulnerabilities it's remarkably secure. @LaceySnr's solution isn't vulnerable to XSS (and should be posted as a solution!)

Comment: All add something as well just in case people trip over this later down the line... wasn't entirely sure if your form was dynamic or not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the LEFT function to take just the first three characters of the parameter, something like: `{!JSINHTMLENCODE(LEFT($CurrentPage.parameters.cts, 3)}`.

You can find a full [list of available funcitions in the visualforce documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm).

The JSINHTMLENCODE function prevents any HTML or javascript special characters from being treated literally - imagine if cts contained a quote and mallicious javascript. If the quote wasn't escaped it would allow anybody to create a URL that runs any javascript on whoever clicks it, which is really, really bad. This is known as [XSS or Cross-Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Thanks ca_peterson! That's exactly what I was looking for. And yes, that's also the type of XSS I want to prevent.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specifically need to control visibility of the form via javascript you can do this with straight Visualforce too, for example the form below would only be rendered if the parameter `example` had the value `yes`.

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.example == 'yes'}">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:inputField value="{!SomeObj.SomeField}"/>
    <!-- etc. -->
  </apex:form>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: This is the solution I went with, so, many thanks LaceySnr. For future visits to this page, I'm leaving ca_peterson's solution marked as the official solution, since it precisely solves the original question asked.